# Let $R$ and $S$ be symmetric relations from $A$ to $B$, prove that $R-S$ is symmetric

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

My attempt:

**Suppose** $(a,b) ∈ R-S$.

**This implies** $(a,b) ∈ R$ and $(a,b) ∉ S$.

**By assumption**, $\forall a,b \in R$, $(a,b) \in R \Rightarrow (b,a) \in R$ **as $R$ is symmetric**

**Also by assumption**,
 $(b,a) \notin S$.
**So we conclude** $(b,a) ∈ R-S$.

**Thus,** $R-S$ **is symmetric**.

Comment: You also need to justify that $(b,a) \not\in S$ before you can claim that $(b,a) \in R-S$.

Comment: @AnuragA thanks, I've just corrected it.

Comment: Why $(b,a) \notin S$ implies $(b,a) \in R - S$?